# Cannot move/do anything in Pokemon Go tutorial

Tags: pokemon-go

Its only the tutorial, but is it because I cannot get a GPS signal? High accuracy location is on and a GPS app and maps pick up location fine.

Comment: Yes, you need a GPS signal in order to move correctly. If you use mock GPS or a GPS faking app that's bad luck. You need to turn that off and use your device's GPS.

Comment: Also, make sure your internet connection (either WiFi or 3/4G) is turned on and stable.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes I'm using the device's GPS and not a mock one; I meant the signal was checked via a gps-checking app in my original post.. Wifi is a stable home network connection.

Answer (score 1):

Your GPS signal may be weak, or your app is experiencing issues due to the servers being overcrowded with Pokemon Go players.

Make sure your Mobile Data is on and running or, if available, a mobile hotspot or WiFi is enabled and working fine.

Comment: You're probably right, re the overload. But neither mobile data nor a wifi connection function when they do for any other application except Pokemon go.

Answer (score 0):

As in most cases with PokemonGo "Bugs" the key to the solution are the server problems.
As long as the servers are working at maximum capacity there will always be problems, not for everyone and not everytime but sometimes for some people.

> High accuracy location is on and a GPS app and maps pick up location fine.

Should have made that clear for your already

Comment: Thanks for the reply Boum. I'm sure its part of the issue, but at no time have I ever been able to achieve a gps connection to get into the tutorial, with either mobile data or wifi. Appreciate your comments though, thanks.

Comment: Hmm, strange.
Im having these problems some times too (right now I'm having 4G but no GPS...), but at least it works about 80% of the time

Comment: Right, so it might just be server-related. I'm in Australia so we got Pokemon go at first launch...maybe its maxxed out or something. I wouldn't mind being able to start the tutorial though lol